# Could not load type example.site1

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem with my asp.net web site. I developed a project from visual studio. It works succesfully on visual studio. But when i published it to a folder and then to ftp it gives me this error.

```
    Server Error in '/' Application.

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'BerksanWebSite.Site1'.

Source Error: 


Line 1:  <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site1.master.cs" Inherits="BerksanWebSite.Site1" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Source File: /webdeneme/Site1.Master    Line: 1 

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.33440
```

Can anybody help me. I found some solves but they don't work

Comment: did you deploy some dll's in the bin folder?

Comment: i see my site's dll's on bin folder -in my published folder-

Comment: AjaxControlToolkit.dll
BerksanWebSite.dll
BerksanWebSite.pdb
CKEditor.NET.dll
CKEditor.NET.pdb
CKFinder.dll
CKFinder.pdb

Here is my bin folder @FelicePollano

Answer (score 0):

I am almost sure that your page class is named differently

it says "Could not load type 'BerksanWebSite.Site1'.", which means that it cant find this class.

in your code behind for this page, you should have this class declared this way:

```
public partial class Site1: System.Web.UI.Page
```

and your namespace is probably `BerksanWebSite`

first thing to do is try to change

```
Inherits="BerksanWebSite.Site1"
```

to:

```
Inherits="Site1"
```

another thing to check is if your page is located in a folder.
what does it mean - i means that if your page is located in a folder named for example "pages",

 your class will be named `pages_Site1` and your need to change it or the `Inherits` so they would both be the same.

Comment: when i  change it to site1 the cs file doesn't find form elements :S

Answer (score 0):

Do this change in your `Page Directive` i.e. Line 1.

`CodeFile="Site1.master.cs"` instead of `CodeBehind="Site1.master.cs"`

It once worked for me.